# stereo reconstruction of point cloud based on rectified images

Tags: opencv, stereo-3d

I have a pair of matched 2D features extracted from rectified stereo image. Using cvPerspectiveTransform function in OpenCV, I attempted to reconstruct those features in 3D. The result is not consistent with the actual object dimension in real world. I realize there is a function in Matlab calibration toolbox that converts 2D stereo features into 3D point cloud. Nevertheless, the features are lifted from original images.

If I want to work with rectified images, is it possible to reconstruct the 3D locations based on 2D feature locations and disparity information.

Comment: Try this: http://www.agisoft.ru/products/stereoscan/

Answer (score 3):

If you know the focal length (f) and the baseline width (b, the distance of the projection axis of both cameras) as well as the disparity (d) **in a rectified stereo image pair**, you can calculate the distance (Z) with the following formula:

```
Z = f*(b/d);
```

This follows from the following equations:

```
x_l = f*(X/Z);  // projecting a 3D point onto the left image
x_r = f*((X+b)/Z);  // projecting the same 3D point onto the right image
d = x_r - x_l = f * (b/Z); // calculating the disparity
```

Solving the last equation for `Z` should lead to the formula given above.